# Sequencia de caracteres com Marquee em C#

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que passa algumas informações aos usuários que estiverem rodando ela. A ideia principal é fazer uma faixa informativa, porem eu estou com dois problemas que devem ser simples, o que eu gostaria que assim que começasse a entrar as palavras a esquerda, elas imediatamente aparecerem na direita, como é a maioria.

Fica o código para maior esclarecimento.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"\\...\Texto de Exemplo.txt", Encoding.UTF7);

            label1.Text = text;

            label1.Left -= 7;

            if (label1.Left < 0 && (Math.Abs(label1.Left) > label1.Width))
            {
                label1.Left = this.Width;
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Left = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
            timer1.Start();

            int c = Screen.PrimaryScreen.BitsPerPixel;
            int w = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
            int h = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;

            int altura, largura;
            altura = h - 77;
            largura = w - 10;

            Width = largura;

            Top = altura;
            Left = 4;

            string f;
            f = "teste";
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado obtido ate agora:
[image: Ele funciona dessa forma]

Comment: tem algum esboço / modelo do q vc quer ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis não tenho um especifico, procurei mas não achei um que se encaixe no que eu quero, eu achei vários que são iguais ou próximos ao meu

Comment: @M.Marins Para o marquee você consegue o efeito, com certo custo, utilizando um Timer mesmo... mas essa "apresentação fantasma" do form eu não faço ideia de como você poderia fazer

Comment: @LeandroAngelo eu estou pesquisando bastante, achei um efeito chamado IsHitTestVisible que tem como ser utilizado no WPF, porem não estou conseguindo utilizar ele fora, e para fazer o que eu fiz em WPF não é tão simples, e não tenho certeza se dá...

Comment: imagino que seja algo assim: https://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_marquee_code.cfm porém pra windows forms. mas esclareça "assim que começasse a entrar as palavras a esquerda, elas imediatamente aparecerem na direita", em que posição isso estaria na tela ?!... cadê sua tela atual ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis eu editei a publicação para facilitar...

Answer (score 0):

- No seu Form, defina as seguintes propriedades:

  ```
  BackColor = 218; 255; 195;
  FormBorderStyle = None;
  Opacity = 70%;
  ShowInTaskbar = False;
  StartPosition = Manual;
  TopMost = True;
  Height = 50;
  ```

> Todas essas opções podem ser alteradas pela janela `Properties` do Visual Studio.

- Adicione um Timer (aqui chamado de timer1) no Form, e defina o intervalo para 50 milisegundos. Crie o evento `Tick`.
- Agora, defina o código do Form para:

  ```
  public partial class FormMarquee : Form
  {
      public Font FonteCaption { get; set; } = new Font("Calibri", 16, FontStyle.Bold);
      public Color ColorCaption { get; set; } = Color.FromArgb(20, 74, 35);
      public int Interval { get { return timer1.Interval; } set { timer1.Interval = value; } }
      public string Caption { get; set; } = "Caption";
      int atualX;
      Graphics g;

      public FormMarquee()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
          SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
          this.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
          this.Location = new Point(0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height);

      }

      protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
      {
          base.OnShown(e);

          g = this.CreateGraphics();

          SizeF s = g.MeasureString(this.Caption, this.FonteCaption);
          atualX = (int)(this.Width - s.Width);

          timer1.Enabled = true;
      }

      private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          timer1.Enabled = false;

          g.Clear(this.BackColor);

          SizeF s = g.MeasureString(this.Caption, this.FonteCaption);
          int y = (int)((this.Height - s.Height) / 2);
          int startX = (int)(this.Width - s.Width);
          int limitX = (int)(s.Width * -1);


          g.DrawString(this.Caption, this.FonteCaption, new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(this.ColorCaption), new PointF(atualX, y));

          if (atualX < 0)
          {
              int x2 = this.Width + atualX;
              g.DrawString(this.Caption, this.FonteCaption, new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(this.ColorCaption), new PointF(x2, y));
          }

          atualX -= 10;

          if (atualX < limitX)
          {
              atualX = startX;
          }

          timer1.Enabled = true;
      }


  }
  ```

> Utilização:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormMarquee form = new FormMarquee();
    form.Caption = "<<- Exemplo Mensagem Marquee - Rodando... ";
    form.Show();
}
```

> Resultado:
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>   (em breve coloco uma animação com o resultado)

Não consegui resolver umas "piscadas" que o texto dá, com mais tempo tento resolver.

Comment: infelizmente eu não consegui implantar esse modelo no meu, eu fiz um novo e funcionou bem, mas essa piscada acaba atrapalhando também, qual seria a parte que faz com que ele retorne?

Comment: @M.Marins a questão é que não uso um Label, se fosse, deveriam ser 2, um pra cada lado e controlar a posição de ambos. Eu uso o `Graphics` pra escrever na tela, e se o `atualX` for negativo, a diferença eu escrevo do outro lado da tela... A questão das piscadas tem como resolver, mas preciso pesquisar um pouco

Comment: eu tentei fazer isso uma vez, mas tive problemas porque essa mensagem muda então o tamanho acaba complicando, como eu pega a mensagem de um txt ela fica bem imprevisível.

Comment: do jeito que fiz, ele calcula a posição em tempo real, o único problema é se a mensagem for maior que a tela... aí tem que diminuir a fonte

Comment: Sim, é bem interessante esse seu código, mas para mim não vai funcionar bem, mas você sabe algo sobre minha outra pergunta, de fazer com que eu possa clicar em cima dessa faixa e atingir o que esta atras dele, eu sei que algumas empresas conseguiram utilizando um efeito estilo ghost, mas só consegui localizar um evento em WPF, mas lá eu não consigo passar esse projeto... Se você souber de algo desse tipo..